# Keep the jupyter notebook running in the background using ssh

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I am connected to a remote server to connect to jupyter notebook using ssh. I use the screen to attach and detach to the session. One problem I am facing is that I have to open two command prompts. One to open the connection which I can work with. The line I use to connect to the ssh  `ssh Ipaddress` and the other one is

```
ssh -NL port:localhost:port host@Ipaddress
```

I have no idea what this line does but it asks for a password and then does nothing. I can attach and detach with the first command prompt connection but if I close this command prompt the jupyter notebook stops running. I cannot even use the screen command in the second one as it does not open the connection

Comment: `man ssh` should be a good starting point for you. Hint: You are creating a local tunnel to access the notebook.

Comment: This feels like a situation where you don't know what you don't know, so aren't able to ask the right questions. The second command opens a tunnel to the remote server so that accessing that port on your machine acts like accessing that port on the remote machine. This is probably what makes your local Jupyter client work. The first command is just a general ssh connection to the remote server, so you can manage things on the server side. Closing the first one should cause any problems unless you aren't detaching from the screen session correctly and thus are also closing the Jupyter server.

Comment: Yes, I don't know what that second command does. But I figured that the second command was opening the port in my computer  and so now I use the screen functionality in the first command and just reconnect in the same port if i disconnect in my computer for the second command and also I have reconnected on the jupyter notebook itself to make it all work.